# How to import mangeto product gallery from magento dataflow profile?

Tags: magento

I just tried to export all products from magento using magento import/export. i got all products with gallery url's in a .CSV file.

But when i tried to import that file in another magento store with same category structure, I got 'small', 'thumbnail' and 'base' images at admin but not able to see any gallery images which is in exported magento store.

How can i get all product gallery images?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To import the images also you need to copy them inside `media/import` folder keeping the rest of the path intact.
For example if you have in the exported file an image names '/i/m/image.jpg', you should copy that image to `media/import/i/m/image.jpg` of your other website.
Magento will take care of the rest (copying the image in the right folder and renaming it of necessary).

**[EDIT]**
For every image you need a new row in the import file. Near the end of the file there should be some columns called `_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled`. These should be filled with the correct values.
Let's take an example. Let's say you have 2 images for a product with SKU `123`. The import file should  look like this (I skipped the rest of the attributes):

```
sku,....,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled
123,....,88,/i/m/image1.jpg,"Some label here",1,0
   ,....,88,/i/m/image2.jpg,"Some other label",2,0
```

As you can see there are 2 rows. One for each image. On the second row all the fields are empty except the ones I mentioned above. (The value for `_media_attribute_id` might be different).

Comment: Hi Marius, yes i also put the images under media/import/. I am getting the "small", "thumbnail" and "base" images but not getting the other product images. It seems that magento neglects product gallery images.

Comment: @Jai I've updated the answer with info on how to import multiple images.

Comment: Hi Marius, Yes i also tried the same thing but got "Can not find required columns: sku" Error on import.

Comment: I had the same problem. Make sure the file encoding is `UTF-8 Without BOM`. If it's `UTF-8 with BOM`, this adds some characters at the beginning of the file that are not ignored while reading it by the import script.

Comment: Hi Marius, I saved the exported CSV file and then opened this CSV file in notepad++, selected the encoding->Convert to UTF-8 without BOM option from Notepad++ menu, And tried again to import, getting the same error "Can not find required columns: sku".